# glutCreateWindow exits with code 1 in Windows 10

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I am trying to go through a basic tutorial posted here (http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=104004&package_id=158526&release_id=463385) and listed on this page (http://gpgpu.org/developer/legacy-gpgpu-graphics-apis). I have also downloaded FreeGlut precompiled libraries for Windows () as well as GLEW headers/libraries.

I am running in Win32 and all my libraries area also the x86 versions.
THe code fails immediately on the 3rd line below with error code 1.

```
int main()
{
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
  glutCreateWindow("Hello, GPGPU! (GLSL version)"); // exits the app

  glutIdleFunc(idle);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

  initialize();

  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add call to glutInit( & argc, argv ).

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni 
Thanks a lot! that solved my problem